# Using the Feathers ScreenNavigator with Starling and Signals

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, starling-framework

I'm new to Flash, Starling, and Feathers and am giving myself a kind of crash course, but am getting confused.  *I simply want my root starling class to initiate my game screen*. I apologize if this is noobish. I really do want to understand.

I am not sure what dispatches FeathersEventType.INITIALIZE and I'm having trouble dispatching it manually.  Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

In my Main.as (my Document Class), I instantiate starling, wait for the Root to be created, and then call its Start function (saw this in an example of how to show an initial background, not sure if it's best practice).

```
this.mStarling = new Starling(Root, this.stage, viewPort);
... //set background from embed
mStarling.addEventListener(starling.events.Event.ROOT_CREATED, 
            function(event:Object, app:Root):void
            {
                mStarling.removeEventListener(starling.events.Event.ROOT_CREATED, arguments.callee);
                removeChild(background);
                background = null;

                var bgTexture:Texture = Texture.fromEmbeddedAsset(
                    backgroundClass, false, false);
                //app.start(bgTexture, assets);
                app.start(bgTexture, assets)  // call the START on my root class
                        mStarling.start();
            });
```

Here's my Root class (which is the root class passed to Starling)

```
public function Root() 
    {
        if (verbose)    trace(this + "Root(" + arguments);
        super();
        this.addEventListener(FeathersEventType.INITIALIZE, initializeHandler);
    }

 // this is not being called
private function initializeHandler(e:Event):void 
    {
        this._navigator.addScreen(GAME_SCREEN, new ScreenNavigatorItem(GameScreen, 
        {
            complete: MAIN_MENU
        }));
    }

public function start(background:Texture, assets:AssetManager):void
    {
        sAssets = assets;  // assets loaded on document class
        addChild(new Image(background));  // passed from doc class

        this._navigator = new ScreenNavigator();
        this.addChild(this._navigator);

        var progressBar:ProgressBar = new ProgressBar(300, 20);
        progressBar.x = (background.width  - progressBar.width)  / 2;
        progressBar.y = (background.height - progressBar.height) / 2;
        progressBar.y = background.height * 0.85;
        addChild(progressBar);

        // Progress bar while assets load
        assets.loadQueue(function onProgress(ratio:Number):void
        {
            progressBar.ratio = ratio;

            if (ratio == 1)
                Starling.juggler.delayCall(function():void
                {
                    gameScreen = new GameScreen();
                                trace("got this far" + gameScreen);
                    gameScreen.GAME_OVER.add(gotoGameOverScreen);

                    gameOverScreen = new GameOverScreen();
                    gameOverScreen.PLAY_AGAIN.add(gotoGameScreen);

                    progressBar.removeFromParent(true);

                    // This is where I'd like the GAME_SCREEN to show.

                    // now would be a good time for a clean-up 
                    System.pauseForGCIfCollectionImminent(0);
                    System.gc();
                }, 0.15);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is part of my Root Class

```
  public function start(background:Texture, assets:AssetManager):void
        {
        stageW=  int(stage.stageWidth);
        stageH = int(stage.stageHeight);


        sAssets = assets;

        bgIma=new Image(background);
        bgIma.height=g.stageH * 0.4;
        bgIma.scaleX=bgIma.scaleY;

        bgIma.x=(g.stageW-bgIma.width)>>1;
        bgIma.y=(g.stageH-bgIma.height)>>1;

        addChild(bgIma);


        var progressBar:ProgressBar = new ProgressBar(175, 20);
        progressBar.x = (g.stageW  - progressBar.width)  >> 1;
        progressBar.y = (g.stageH - progressBar.height) >> 1;
        progressBar.y = g.stageH * 0.8;
        addChild(progressBar);


        assets.loadQueue(function onProgress(ratio:Number):void
        {
            progressBar.ratio = ratio;

            if (ratio == 1)
                Starling.juggler.delayCall(function():void
                {
                    progressBar.removeFromParent(true);
                    removeChild(bgIma);
                    bgIma=null;

                    addedToStageHandler();
                    addSounds();

                    System.pauseForGCIfCollectionImminent(0);
                    System.gc();
                }, 0.15);
        });
    }





    protected function addedToStageHandler(event:starling.events.Event=null):void
    {

        this._navigator = new ScreenNavigator();
        _navigator.autoSizeMode = ScreenNavigator.AUTO_SIZE_MODE_CONTENT; 
        this.addChild( this._navigator );

        this._transitionManager = new ScreenFadeTransitionManager(_navigator);

        this._navigator.addScreen( "Fluocode", new ScreenNavigatorItem(Fluocode));
        this._navigator.addScreen( "Main", new ScreenNavigatorItem(AppMain));

       this._navigator.showScreen("Fluocode");

        this._transitionManager.duration = 0.5;
        this._transitionManager.ease = Transitions.EASE_IN;

    }
```